# Jquery compare two divs, get difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make ajax updater. Now I have div with:

```
<ul class='topStatsOuter'>
   <li class='liClass'>custom text</li>
   <li class='liClass'>custom text two</li>
   <li class='liClass'>custom text three</li>
</ul>
```

Updating ul class:

```
success: function( result ) {                   
    $( '.topStatsOuter' ).empty()

    $.each( result.updatedtopics, function( id, topics )
    {
        $( '.topStatsOuter' ).append( topics.html );
    });
}
```

How can I compare what's inside original div, not updated, with updated div?

For example updated div look like this:

```
<ul class='topStatsOuter'>
   <li class='liClass'>ajax added this li</li>
   <li class='liClass'>custom text</li>
   <li class='liClass'>custom text two</li>
   <li class='liClass'>custom text three</li>
</ul>
```

I want to change style: background after update, of added li, (*ajax added this li*) Is it possible? Looks like I want to get difference between two divs. Thanks, and sorry for my bad english.

---

EDIT. Looks like this is what I want:
http://jsfiddle.net/AzZHy/

Comment: maybe you can compare the length property (number of elements in the `ul`). that would work or you need to compare the contents as well?

Comment: Using the existing DOM you can't. You can. however, copy the unmodified element and write you own comparer to walk the unmodified and modified elements, but I still don't get, why you might need that.

Comment: @AdamWolski yes, I need to compare all li elements. P.S jezeli mozesz, pisz po Polsku, lzej bedzie zrozumiec mi

Comment: @EduardMalakhov because I want to add css effect, and change background color of added li's

Comment: Why don't apply those styles or whatever the same time you add those elements?

Comment: @EduardMalakhov because I add full html code, with all elements, not only with updated, so I want to get difference

Comment: I would suggest only adding new elements. This solution would be much clearer than finding the difference between the existing elements and the new ones.

Comment: @EduardMalakhov ok, thanks !

Comment: here is a working fiddle for you : https://jsfiddle.net/d1qe3fjq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of emptying the `ul` remove all `li` and keep its reference, later when appending check the text content and provide the style.

```
success: function(result) {
  // remove the element from ul and keep it's reference
  var $li = $('.topStatsOuter li').detach();

  $.each(result.updatedtopics, function(id, topics) {
    // wrap html with jQuery, append it to ul and keep it's refernece
    var $ele = $(topics.html).appendTo('.topStatsOuter');
    // compare content with old elements, use filter for exact match
    // or use `:contains()`, eg: if($li.filter(':contains(' + $ele.text().trim() + ')').length){ ... }
    if ($li.filter(function() {
      // check contents are the same after trimming the whitespace
      return $(this).text().trim() == $ele.text().trim();
    }).length)
      // if old element with same content exist then update style
      $ele.css('background', 'red')
  });
}
```

```js
var arr = ["<li class='liClass'>ajax added this li</li>",
  "<li class='liClass'>custom text</li>",
  "<li class='liClass'>custom text two</li>",
  "<li class='liClass'>custom text three</li>"
];

var $li = $('.topStatsOuter li').remove();

$.each(arr, function(id, html) {
  var $ele = $(html).appendTo('.topStatsOuter');
  if ($li.filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() == $ele.text().trim();
  }).length)
    $ele.css('background', 'red')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='topStatsOuter'>
  <li class='liClass'>custom text</li>
  <li class='liClass'>custom text two</li>
  <li class='liClass'>custom text three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Dewagg : `.css('background-color','red')`